# JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList`

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Passing DTO object having two arrays from angular to spring boot rest but getting error "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList`"

Having below dto in angular

but JSON.stringify() not generating valid json.

```
export interface SampleDTO{
    carList:Array<Car>;
    addList:Array<Address>;
}
```

JSON I am deserializing:

```
{"addList":"[{"city":"ABAD","pin":"384567"},{"city":"ABAD","pin":"384567"}]","carList":"[{"name":"Honda","cc":"360"},{"name":"Honda","cc":"360"}]"}
```

Spring Boot Controller :

```
@PostMapping("/get")
ResponseEntity<String> sample(@RequestBody SampleDTO sampleDTO)
```

Pojo :

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class SampleDTO implements Serializable {

    private List<Address> addList;

    private List<Car> carList;

    public List<Address> getAddList() {
        return addList;
    }

    public void setAddList(List<Address> addList) {
        this.addList = addList;
    }

    public List<Car> getCarList() {
        return carList;
    }

    public void setCarList(List<Car> carList) {
        this.carList = carList;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your JSON is "valid", but the lists are strings, not lists

`"addList":"[ ...]", "carList":"[...]"}`

Comment: So what changes i need to do here?

Comment: {
  "addList": [
    {
      "city": "ABAD",
      "pin": "384567"
    },
    {
      "city": "ABAD",
      "pin": "384567"
    }
  ],
  "carList": [
    {
      "name": "Honda",
      "cc": "360"
    },
    {
      "name": "Honda",
      "cc": "360"
    }
  ]
} - This should be your json generated from angular. then spring boot will be able to read it to pojo

Comment: I am not good with angular so will not be able to help on how to generate such json

Comment: I tried this already but how to get this json using angular that i am not able to figure out. Anyway thanks for help.

Comment: Perhaps you should share more of your Javascript code

Answer (score 0):

```
In spring boot[postman request]:
[
{
    "pId":"29932",
    "skuId":10001,
    "skuQty":"10",
    "batch":"200",
    "productCode":"33992"
},
{
    "pId":"29932",
    "skuId":10001,
    "skuQty":"10",
    "batch":"200",
    "productCode":"33992"
}
]
```

Note: In this way can deserialize the instance of `java.util.ArrayList`